# my torrent speed is slower all of the sudden

Tags: connection, utorrent

Last year when I tried to download torrent the speed was around 120 kb/s, but now it's only 10 kbs/s. I'm really confused here.

I have been trying everything that I could find on the internet but nothing seems to work, so I'm really desperate for help. One more thing: I don't know if this will help, but i'm from Malaysia. My internet speed is 1 mb. I tried using all the PCs that I own and all seems to produce the same result.

Comment: Which torrent? Is it the same torrent as last time? Are there the same number of seeds and peers as last time? You realize that each torrent will be different right? One torrent might have a lot of seeds and speed through while another may have very few.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite common and is often referred to as the "rare blocks" problem. When you first started downloading the torrent, you needed every block of the file. Thus you could download from any peer that had any of the file. Now, the number of blocks you need is much smaller and many of the peers you might download from don't have any blocks that you need.

It is normal for a torrent's download speed to go down as the percentage of the torrent that you have goes up. When you have 100%, the speed will, obviously, drop to zero.

Answer (score 1):

If your ISP is either TM net or JARING, it is likely that you are a victim of traffic shaping. This can be applied by the ISP specifically to Bittorrent traffic, high traffic, or both.

http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Bad_ISPs#Malaysia

There are different ways you can try to get around this, like enabling encryption in your Bittorrent client to avoid getting detected, or using a VPN tunnel.

Comment: [Glasnost](http://broadband.mpi-sws.org/transparency/bttest.php) can test if your ISP is throttling or shaping certain types of P2P traffic, email and website protocols and some media types.

Comment: when high traffic is the reason for the ISP's throttling, encryption wont help. you will have to limit your average speed, and maybe pay more for a better connection

Answer (score 0):

**TERMINOLOGY**:

***leechers / peers*** are users downloading from a BitTorrent swarm.

***seeders*** are users that remain connected to a BitTorrent swarm even after they’ve downloaded the complete file, contributing more of their upload bandwidth so other people can continue to download the file.

***Tracker*** is a special server that keeps track of the connected computers.

**HOW BitTorrent  peer-to-peer protocol (P2P) works:**

There is difference between regular download and downlaod using BitTorrent  peer-to-peer protocol (P2P).In your regular download your computer connects to the web server and downloads the data directly from that server.
Where as in P2P downloads your computer joins a BitTorrent swarm by loading a .torrent file into a BitTorrent client.
The BitTorrent client contacts a “tracker” specified in the .torrent file.

In recent times, a decentralized “trackerless” torrent system (DHT) allows BitTorrent clients to communicate among each other without the need for any central servers.you may have used this technology in Magnetic torrents.

Once connected, a BitTorrent client downloads bits of the files in the torrent in small pieces, downloading all the data it can get from the peers as weell as seeders. Once the BitTorrent client has some data, it can then begin to upload that data to other BitTorrent clients in the swarm. In this way, everyone downloading a torrent is also uploading the same torrent.
So in summary , you are downloading from fellow users like youself using BitTorrent  peer-to-peer protocol unlike a central web server which will always be up and running.

**THE ISSUES:**

**1**)If a torrent has no seeders, it won’t be possible to download – no connected user has the complete file.

**2**)Now consider the torrent has a few peers who has partial files.In this case , the problem of rare blocks arises.

**3**)If these peers has less upload bandwidth , say 10 KBps , then you can download only at 10 KBps or lesser.

**4**)Traffic Shaping:Some Internet service providers (ISPs) slow down certain types of traffic, like BitTorrent traffic.This is termed as Traffic Shaping.You can use [Glasnost project](http://broadband.mpi-sws.org/transparency/glasnost.php) which provides web-based tests that can identify whether different types of traffic are being rate-limited.

**5**)Bandwidth Limiting:Some ISPs have been known to do this as a way of enforcing their bandwidth caps. Even ISPs that offer “unlimited” connections may throttle you after you hit a certain, usually large, threshold.

**6**)In BitTorrent, if you are unable to get a green network status icon after a long period of transferring different torrents, it is an indication that you might be in a firewalled state and you are not getting great speeds with BitTorrent.
Check Port Forwarding manual [here](http://www.bittorrent.com/help/manual/chapter0203).

You can read this article here to to find out [12 Clues (and Solutions) to Why Your Torrents Are Slow](http://filesharefreak.com/2009/02/23/12-clues-and-solutions-to-why-your-torrents-are-slow)